# Iterate object inside object

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I'm working with Json Object:

```
var someobj = {
 'key':'value',
 'key':'value',
 'objectkey':{'key':'value','key':'value'}
}
```

While iterating, i want the result in console.log as:

```
KEY: key && VALUE: value
KEY: key && VALUE: value
OKEY: key && OKEYVALUE: value
```

While iterating I only get the first level, I can't seem to get it into the values that are the objects. I guess some sort of length could work:

EDIT2: Now with this inner loop it iterates and I get letters for external values, the inner values get logged completely.

```
var registration_form = {
    'registration_form':{
        'Display Name':'input',
        'Username':{'inpute':'text','id':'some_id'},
        'Password':'input',
        'Email':'input',
        'Captcha':'input'
    }

};
function iterateNodes(data) {
    for (var key in data){
        var obj = data[key];

        for(var prop in obj){
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                var inobj = obj[prop];
                for(var prop in inobj){
                    console.log(inobj[prop])
                }
            }else{
                console.log(obj)
            }

        }
    }
}
iterateNodes(registration_form);
```

Comment: Did you try to use simple for loops?

Comment: Please spend couple more minutes and create an example that makes some sense. You at least should have unique keys and different values so that it was obvious what is the connection between input and output.

Comment: you can use recursion for access to nested objects, but possibly you need simple [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 2):

In general you can iterate over properties of an object in this way:

```
for (var k in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        console.log('k: ' + k + ', v: ' + o[k])
    }
}
```

so you can use recursion to go deeper than one level

```
function hasproperty(o) {
    if (typeof o === 'object') {
        for (var k in o) {
            if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                return true;
            }
        }    
    }

    return false;
};

function iterate(o) {
    for (var k in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            if (hasproperty(o[k])) {
                console.log('within ' + k);
                iterate(o[k]);
                console.log('exit ' + k);
            } else {
                console.log('K: ' + k +  ', V:' + o[k]);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: that looks ok to me, im going to try this out, i like the recursion and the itterate function, kinda breaks down the logic very nice

Comment: i cant seem to get this working, could you try this on the given example object in question please?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have the pointers i need from all your answers! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out:

```
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var someobj = {
      'key1':'value1',
      'key2':'value2',
      'objectkey3':{'key01':'value01','key02':'value02'}
     };

  jQuery.each(someobj, function(i, val) {

        if (typeof val == 'string'){
            console.log("key : "+i+" value: "+val);
        }else{

            jQuery.each(val, function(j, val2) {
                console.log("key : "+j+" value: "+val2);
            });
        }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your try, that iterates only the first level returning object Object on values that inlcude objects. (

Comment: the idea of checking if its string or object sounds good, but for some reason it again returns first level only

Comment: If val is Integer, Boolean? If there are three (or more) level?

Comment: the recursion idea looks interesting, that way we dont have to worry about the types )

Comment: Thank you for your efforts it helps a lot! Have a great day!